# Spark executors and shuffle in local mode

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am running a [TPC-DS benchmark](https://github.com/databricks/spark-sql-perf) for Spark 3.0.1 in local mode and using [sparkMeasure](https://db-blog.web.cern.ch/blog/luca-canali/2018-08-sparkmeasure-tool-performance-troubleshooting-apache-spark-workloads) to get workload statistics. I have 16 total cores and SparkContext is available as

> Spark context available as 'sc' (master = local[*], app id = local-1623251009819)

Q1. For `local[*]`, driver and executors are created in a single JVM with 16 threads. Considering Spark's configuration which of the following will be true?

- 1 worker instance, 1 executor having 16 cores/threads
- 1 worker instance, 16 executors each having 1 core

For a particular query, sparkMeasure reports shuffle data as follows

> shuffleRecordsRead => 183364403 
> shuffleTotalBlocksFetched => 52582 
> shuffleTotalBlocksFetched => 52582 
> shuffleLocalBlocksFetched => 52582 
> shuffleRemoteBlocksFetched => 0 
> shuffleTotalBytesRead => 1570948723 (1498.0 MB) 
> shuffleLocalBytesRead => 1570948723 (1498.0 MB) 
> shuffleRemoteBytesRead => 0 (0 Bytes) 
> shuffleRemoteBytesReadToDisk => 0 (0 Bytes) 
> shuffleBytesWritten => 1570948723 (1498.0 MB) 
> shuffleRecordsWritten => 183364480

Q2. Regardless of the query specifics, why is there data shuffling when everything is inside a single JVM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- executor is a jvm process when you use `local[*]` you run Spark
  **locally** with **as many worker threads as logical cores on your machine** so :  1 executor and as many worker threads as logical
  cores. when you configure `SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES=5` in `spark-env.sh`  and execute these commands `start-master.sh` and `start-slave.sh spark://local:7077` to bring up a standalone spark cluster in your
  local machine you have one master and 5 workers, if you want to send
  your application to this cluster you must configure application like
  `SparkSession.builder().appName("app").master("spark://localhost:7077")`
  in this case you can't specify `[*]` or `[2]` for example. but when
  you specify master to be `local[*]` a jvm process is created and
  master and all workers will be in that jvm process and after your
  application finished that jvm instance will be destroyed. `local[*]`
  and `spark://localhost:7077`  are two separate things.
- workers do their job using tasks and each task actually is a thread
  i.e. `task = thread`. workers have memory and they assign a memory
  partition to each task in order to they do their job such as reading
  a part of a dataset into its own memory partition or do a
  transformation on read data. when a task such as join needs other
  partitions, shuffle occurs regardless weather the job is ran in
  cluster or local. if you were in cluster there is a possibility that
  two tasks were in different machines so Network transmission will be
  added to other stuffs such as writing the result and then reading by
  another task. in local if task B needs the data in the partition of
  the task A, task A should write it down and then task B will read it
  to do its job

Comment: By worker I meant "worker instances" which generally is controlled by SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES in spark-env.sh (updated). I understand that in a single JVM "worker threads equal to the number of cores" are spawned.

Answer (score 1):

Local mode is the same as non-distributed single-JVM deployment mode.

> Q1: It is neither. In this mode Spark spawns all execution components
>
> - namely Driver, *n `threads` for data processing* and Master in a single JVM.
>
> If I had to abstract it to one of your 2 options I would say, 1 worker
> instance, 16 executors each having 1 core, but as said this is not the
> right way to look at it. The other option could be N Workers with M Executors with 1 Core each where N x M = 16.
>
> The default parallelism is the number of threads as specified in the
> master URL = local[*].

> Q2: The threads will service partitions, concurrently, one at a time,
> as many as needed, sequentially within the current `Stage`, being
> assigned by the Driver when free. A stage is a boundary that causes
> `shuffling`, regardless of how you run, in YARN Cluster or local.
>
> Shuffling - what is that then? Shuffle occurs when data is required to
> be re-arranged over existing partitions. E.g. a groupBy or orderBy? We
> may have M partitions and after the groupBy N partitions. This is a
> wide-transformation concept  at the core of Spark for parallel
> processing, so (even) with local[*] this will apply.